# Trying to pluck row values and display as column values with multiple where clauses in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT id, user_uid, charity_id, value FROM donations
WHERE charity_id IN (178, 25, 209, 150, 176)
AND year = 2022
ORDER BY value DESC
```

Which outputs the following table:

| id | user_uid | charity_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 267558 | 1a36d6c1-3eca-4a23-a3c7-2827acca3397 | 178 | 905 |
| 267552 | 1a36d6c1-3eca-4a23-a3c7-2827acca3397 | 25 | 630 |
| 92944 | 03661b7a-56d0-43e1-9d5e-3f913cf8fefd | 178 | 575 |
| ... |  |  |  |
| 271876 | a620d031-c947-4513-b307-7bafb526789a | 150 | 305 |
| 95444 | 03661b7a-56d0-43e1-9d5e-3f913cf8fefd | 176 | 300 |

But I'm trying to output it in the following format:

| user_uid | charity_178 | charity_25 | charity_209 | charity_150 | charity_176 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a36d6c1-3eca-4a23-a3c7-2827acca3397 | 905 | 630 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 03661b7a-56d0-43e1-9d5e-3f913cf8fefd | 575 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 300 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |
| a620d031-c947-4513-b307-7bafb526789a | NULL | 30 | NULL | 305 | NULL |

I've tried the following, which I thought should work...

```
SELECT
    fun.uid,
    d1.value AS 'charity_178',
    d2.value AS 'charity_209',
    d3.value AS 'charity_25',
    d4.value AS 'charity_150',
    d5.value AS 'charity_176'
FROM `fundraisers` AS fun
    JOIN `donations` AS d1 ON fun.uid = d1.user_uid
    JOIN `donations` AS d2 ON fun.uid = d2.user_uid
    JOIN `donations` AS d3 ON fun.uid = d3.user_uid
    JOIN `donations` AS d4 ON fun.uid = d4.user_uid
    JOIN `donations` AS d5 ON fun.uid = d5.user_uid
WHERE d1.year = 2022
    AND d1.charity = 178
    AND d2.year = 2022
    AND d2.charity = 209
    AND d3.year = 2022
    AND d3.charity = 25
    AND d4.year = 2022
    AND d4.charity = 150
    AND d5.year = 2022
    AND d5.charity = 176
```

But it isn't joining anything that is missing or null in the `donations` table.

So only returns something like this:

| user_uid | charity_178 | charity_25 | charity_209 | charity_150 | charity_176 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2cd3f974-4cc4-4b89-9bad-475321b68c83 | 200 | 10 | 100 | 340 | 90 |

With a *lot* of users missing.

---

FWIW, I'm actually doing this in a Laravel application, but the dataset is large and trying to manipulate a collection in this format is killing the server, so I'm trying to move the work to the database and using the DB facade with a dynamically created sql string and `DB::RAW($sql)`

Comment: Potentially! I had a search and didn't see this as result, so I'll give it a try. Cheers @user1191247

Answer (score 1):

From the question/answer suggested by @user1191247, I can use conditional aggregation.

The following code works in my example:

```
SELECT user_uid,
    MAX(CASE WHEN charity_id = 178 THEN value END) "charity_178",
    MAX(CASE WHEN charity_id = 209 THEN value END) "charity_209",
    MAX(CASE WHEN charity_id = 25 THEN value END) "charity_25",
    MAX(CASE WHEN charity_id = 150 THEN value END) "charity_150",
    MAX(CASE WHEN charity_id = 176 THEN value END) "charity_176"
FROM donations
GROUP BY user_uid;
```